# Processing references from YAML files

Tags: perl, parsing, yaml

I parsed a YAML file as below:

```
test_control:
 standalone_execution: yes 
 code_checkout: no #yes/no  

rules_file: 
 - rules_file_id: &rulesid_01 
    name:         
    hostname: 
    path: /local/home/hanmaghu
 - rules_file_id: &rulesid_02
    name:         
    hostname: NA
    path: NA

run_target_platforms: 
 - run_target_id: &runid_01
    target_controls:
     run_target_type: simulator    #simulator, emulator , hardware
     run_target_active: yes
    target_connection_info: 
     run_target_hostname: 
     run_target_ipaddr: unknown

standalone_execution:  
 utpsm_executable:   
  hostname: 
  hostip: NA
  name: tpsm     
 rulesfile: [*rulesid_01]
 target_list: [*runid_01]
...
```

as you observe the last two lines are arrays pointing to references `rulesid_01` and `runid_01`. I have taken most of the variables ( after parsing ) but now I don't know how to take the reference variables

Here is part of my Perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use YAML_Lib;
use YAML::XS;

my $input_file;
my $yaml_input;

if ( scalar(@ARGV) < 1 ) {
    print("USAGE:: $0 <Input file>\n");
    exit(0);
}

$input_file = $ARGV[0];
print "Input File = $input_file\n";

# parse the yaml file
$yaml_input = YAML::XS::LoadFile("$input_file");
&YAML_Lib::parse_yaml($yaml_input);
```

This library I have written (function) `parse_yaml` as follows :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
package YAML_Lib;

use YAML::XS;
use Exporter 'import';

# function declarations

sub parse_yaml_testcontrol($);
sub parse_yaml_run_tgt($);
sub parse_yaml_standalone($);
sub parse_yaml_rulesfile($);

########## Start parsing YAML stream ##########

sub parse_yaml($) {
    my ($yaml_input) = @_;

    print "in parse yaml \n";

    parse_yaml_testcontrol($yaml_input);
    parse_yaml_run_tgt($yaml_input);
    parse_yaml_standalone($yaml_input);
    parse_yaml_rulesfile($yaml_input);
}

#test-control
sub parse_yaml_testcontrol($) {
    my ($yaml_input) = @_;

    $test_control         = $yaml_input->{test_control};
    $standalone_execution = $test_control->{standalone_execution};
    $code_checkout        = $test_control->{code_checkout};
}

#standalone execution
sub parse_yaml_standalone($) {
    my ($yaml_input) = @_;

    $standalone_exec = $yaml_input->{standalone_execution};
    $utpsm_exec      = $standalone_exec->{utpsm_executable};
    $se_hostname     = $utpsm_exec->{hostname};
    $se_tgt_list     = $standalone_exec->{target_list};
    $se_rulesfile    = $standalone_exec->{rulesfile};

    print "$se_tgt_list->$run_target_controls[0]->$run_target_types[0]\n";

    #print "\n $se_tgt_list, $se_name , $se_hostname, $se_username ,$se_password, $se_path ,$se_rulesfile \n";
}
```

I am sharing some part of code. I think not all fields will make sense.

I want to know how I should parse variables of the reference ( `$se_tgt_list` and `$se_rulesfile`). when I print these two variables I get arrays ( because I have used `[]`. I want them as arrays but I want to know how to parse them.

Comment: [Crossposted](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1167060).

Comment: Hi, i only posted there in perlmonks, unable to get a solution , i have tried here , pls help

Comment: You're misunderstanding the meaning of ***parsing***. The `YAML::XS` module is doing all the parsing, and is returning a Perl data structure that is equivalent to the YAML data you started with. That means all of your library function names are misnomers, as they are not parsing anything. You also *must never* use prototypes on Perl subroutines. You code is correct without `($)`; and you shouldn't use an ampersand `&` when calling Perl subroutines. Whatever tutorial you got that idea from urgently needs updating, as it hasn't been best practice since Perl v5.0 was released 22 years ago

Comment: I found the solution myself : please check the crossposted

Comment: @Borodin:  please tell me then how to call package functions if not with &PackageName:: Package_func()

Comment: @hanish: Just `PackageName::package_func()` is correct (please be careful that only global identifiers should be capitalised). But your `PackageName.pm` should probably have been written using [Exporter](https://metacpan.org/pod/Exporter), so that the calling code needs to say only `package_func()`.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, you're misunderstanding what *parsing* is, and your library functions are just navigating a Perl data structure generated by `YAML::XS`, which did all the necessary parsing of your YAML data. You really don't need that library, as all it is doing is making copies of some elements of a nested Perl data structure

Your question is very unclear, and I don't understand *"I don't know how to take the reference variables"* or *"I want them as arrays but I want to know how to parse them"* but I suspect the problem is that you are creating single-element arrays in your YAML

```
rulesfile: [*rulesid_01]
target_list: [*runid_01]
```

So in this block

```
$standalone_exec = $yaml_input->{standalone_execution};

$utpsm_exec      = $standalone_exec->{utpsm_executable};
$se_hostname     = $utpsm_exec->{hostname};

$se_tgt_list     = $standalone_exec->{target_list};
$se_rulesfile    = $standalone_exec->{rulesfile};
```

Your `$se_tgt_list` and `$se_rulesfile` are references to one-element arrays

Just as you use a reference to a hash to access a hash element with `$href->{$key}`, you use a reference to an array to access an array element with `$aref->[$i]`

Because of the references in the YAML, `$yaml_input->{standalone_execution}{target_list}[0]` is a reference to the same hash as `$yaml_input->{run_target_platforms}[0]{run_target_id}` and you can process it in exactly the same way

You don't show your code for `parse_yaml_rulesfile`, but you should use the same technique as you did there

Comment: yes, maybe i didnt put in proper words, actually i have more elements in the array for now i am showing it just one. my point was after parsing from the module , the data structure in perl had to be resolved based on the references in the yaml file. for which i used the above approach.